# xsd:Import doesn't work in WSDL?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xsd, wsdl

When put below wsdl into my VS2010 project I got a "Type 'urn:listing3:Phone' is not declared." error. Looks like the xsd:import doesn't work, why?

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="urn:listing2"
                  xmlns:tns="urn:listing2"
                  xmlns:listing3="urn:listing3"
                  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
                  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:listing3"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
      <xsd:complexType name="Phone">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="areaCode" type="xsd:int"/>
          <xsd:element name="exchange" type="xsd:int"/>
          <xsd:element name="number" type="xsd:int"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:schema>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:listing2"
                xmlns:listing3="urn:listing3"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xsd:import namespace="urn:listing3"/>
      <xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
      <xsd:complexType name="Address">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="streetNum" type="xsd:int"/>
          <xsd:element name="streetName" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element name="city" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element name="state" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element name="phone" type="listing3:Phone"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>

  <wsdl:message name="GetAddressRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetAddressResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="address" type="tns:Address"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetPhoneRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetPhoneResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="phone" type="listing3:Phone"/>
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:portType name="AddressBook">
    <wsdl:operation name="getAddress">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetAddressRequest"/>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetAddressResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getPhone">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetPhoneRequest"/>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetPhoneResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

The error is, type Phone is declared in namespace listing3, the namespace is also imported in namespace listing2 using `<xsd:import>`, but type Phone cannot be referenced in listing2. The error message is "Type 'urn:listing3:Phone' is not declared".

**Update**:
The wsdl was generated automatically by VS2010 when adding the Java web service as a web reference. The wsdl I posted here actually is not the real wsdl but a fake one for security reason. But the structure of both wsdl and the error messages are almost same.

Comment: Exactly where do you get this error? Exactly what did you do to get the error?

Comment: John,

The problem is the type Phone declared in namespace listing3 cannot be referenced in namespace listing2 as a type.

Comment: Bruce, you didn't answer my question. Exactly what are you doing with this WSDL? What do you mean, "When put below wsdl into my VS2010 project"? Tell us step by step what you are doing.